# Function that returns the sum of all numbers passed in arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, sum, arguments

I need help. Can you help me to solve this task.

> Write the function that returns the summ of all numbers even string numbers that are passed as arguments and the amount of these numbers is unlimited.
>   If one of the parameters is an array, then
>   Sum is also added to the sum of the values of this array (if any of the
>   Values of this array is also an array, then the result is added
>   Also the sum of its values, and so on).

```
var sum = getSum (1, '1', 'one', [2, '2', 'two']);
console.log(sum);
```

I've tried to write something like this:

```
function getSum(){
    var separeted = string.split(",");
    var sum =0; 
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){

        sum += parseInt(arguments[i].toString()..match(/(\d+)/));

    }
   return sum;
}
var sum = getSum(1,"1","one",[2,'2', 'two']);
console.log(sum);
```

and here I've stacked. I think that I will need split and filter but how to combine that all in one function I can't find.
Thanks.

Comment: By "string number" it probably only means "2" not "two" or you'll be there all day trying to write code capturing all instances of numbers-as-words.

Comment: This sounds like an interview question or assignment... I'm not sure we should be answering for you.

Comment: I would just flatten the arrays

Comment: Yeah, but those two lines are from the task. So I can't touche those.

Comment: @andy `"onethousandthreehundredandthirtyseven"`

Comment: And I'm still learning so that's not an interview question.

 epascarello, Thanks will try it.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a recursive function like so:

```js
function getSum () {
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce((sum, value) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      sum += getSum.apply(this, value)
    } else {
      sum += Number(value)
    }

    return sum
  }, 0)
}

var sum = getSum (1, '1', '3', [2, '2', '10']);

console.log(sum);
```

In order to account for string numbers, you must define a mapping from words to numbers and iteratively traverse the string of words to generate the number. Here's a possible implementation of that:

```js
var stringToNumber = (function () {
  const primary = new Map([
    ['zero', 0],
    ['one', 1],
    ['two', 2],
    ['three', 3],
    ['four', 4],
    ['five', 5],
    ['six', 6],
    ['seven', 7],
    ['eight', 8],
    ['nine', 9]
  ])
  
  const secondary = new Map([
    ['ten', 10],
    ['eleven', 11],
    ['twelve', 12],
    ['thirteen', 13],
    ['fourteen', 14],
    ['fifteen', 15],
    ['sixteen', 16],
    ['seventeen', 17],
    ['eighteen', 18],
    ['nineteen', 19]
  ])
  
  const prefix = new Map([
    ['twenty', 20],
    ['thirty', 30],
    ['forty', 40],
    ['fifty', 50],
    ['sixty', 60],
    ['seventy', 70],
    ['eighty', 80],
    ['ninety', 90]
  ])

  const magnitude = new Map([
    ['hundred', 1e2],
    ['thousand', 1e3],
    ['million', 1e6],
    ['billion', 1e9],
    ['trillion', 1e12],
    ['quadrillion', 1e15],
    ['quintillion', 1e18],
    ['sextillion', 1e21],
    ['septillion', 1e24],
    ['octillion', 1e27],
    ['nonillion', 1e30],
    ['decillion', 1e33]
  ])
  
  const types = { primary, secondary, prefix, magnitude }

  class Parser {
    static parse(word) {
      if (isNaN(word)) {
        const [type = null] = Object.keys(types)
          .filter(type => types[type].has(word))
        const value = types[type] ? types[type].get(word) : NaN
        
        return { type, sign: 1, value }
      } else {
        const value = Math.abs(word)
        const sign = Math.sign(word)
        const [type = 'primary'] = Object.keys(types)
          .filter(type => Array.from(types[type].values()).includes(value))

        return { type, sign, value }
      }
    }

    constructor() {
      this.words = []
    }
    
    push(word) {
      const parsed = Parser.parse(word)
      
      if (parsed.type === null) {
        return this.words.length
      }
      
      return this.words.push(parsed)
    }
    
    valueOf() {
      if (this.words.length === 0) {
        return NaN
      }
      
      const words = this.words

      let total = 0
      let { type: lastType, sign, value: run } = words[0]
      let maxMagnitude = lastType === 'magnitude' ? run : 1
      
      for (const { type, value } of words.slice(1)) {
        switch (type) {
          case 'magnitude':
            if (value > maxMagnitude) {
              run = (total + run) * value
              total = 0
              maxMagnitude = value
            } else {
              run *= value
            }
            break
          case 'secondary':
          case 'prefix':
            switch (lastType) {
              case 'magnitude':
                total += run
                run = value
                break
              case 'primary':
              case 'secondary':
              case 'prefix':
                run = Number(String(run) + String(value))
            }
            break
          case 'primary':
            switch (lastType) {
              case 'magnitude':
                total += run
                run = value
                break
              case 'prefix':
                run += value
                break
              case 'primary':
              case 'secondary':
                run = Number(String(run) + String(value))
            }
        }
        
        lastType = type
      }
      
      return sign * (total + run)
    }
  }

  return function stringToNumber (string) {
    const words = string
      .trim()
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(/\s+/g)

    const parser = new Parser()
    
    for (const word of words) {
      parser.push(word)
    }
    
    return parser.valueOf()
  }
})()

function getSum () {
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce((sum, value) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      sum += getSum.apply(this, value)
    } else if (!isNaN(value)) {
      sum += Number(value)
    } else {
      sum += stringToNumber(String(value))
    }

    return sum
  }, 0)
}

var sum = getSum (1, '1', 'one hundred thousand', [2, '2', 'twenty six hundred']);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: But you also need to account for 'one' and 'two' according to the OP :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts your casual disregard for the OP's requirements is certainly your prerogative... as are your expectations for voting patterns.   Whether the latter correlates with reality...

Comment: Thank you.) With those strings I can use check for isNaN I think.

Comment: @Ksyju `isNaN("one") // true`

Comment: @canon I did find a few (albeit buggy) possible drop-in solutions. Unfortunately, the best lead is a repository, called [words to numbers](https://github.com/finnfiddle/words-to-numbers), which does not commit the `dist/` directory, and there is no CDN available of any of the libraries I've found. I did find an answer on Stack Overflow, which incidentally led to the creation of the package above. However, the answer there uses poor coding practices, and I'd rather not propagate them in one of my answers. When I have more time, perhaps this evening I'll extend my solution to accommodate words.

Comment: @canon implemented

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone I found the solution in the old "O'reilly Javascript by David Flanagan"

so as I thought in my loop I had to check if it's not null than change the element into `Number()`
Here is the code from the book

```
function flexisum(a) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var element = arguments[i], n;
        if (element == null) continue; // Ignore null & undefined
        if (isArray(element))          // if argument is array
            n = flexisum.apply(this, element);  // count sum of all elements
        else if (typeof element === "function") // if it's a function
            n = Number(element());              // call and convert it to the 'number'
        else n = Number(element);      // or to convert it anyway
        if (isNaN(n)) // If it was not possible to convert to a number, initiate exc.
            throw Error("flexisum(): can't convert " + element +
                        "into the number");
        total += n;   // Otherwise, add n to the total
    }
    return total;
}
```

but in my case I've chaged it for my needs and took away the exc. so it could count sum without string words.

```
if (isNaN(n)) continue;
  total += n;
```

}

So, thanks to everybody.
Books are the good sourse))))

Comment: I updated my answer to support word strings if you want to check that out

Answer (score -2):

i think need to iterate any number of label ,so you can use following method

```
   function jsArrSum(arr) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] == 'object')
          sum += jsArrSum(arr[i]);
        else
          sum += arr[i];
      }
      return sum;
    }

    jsArrSum(array);
```

Comment: @canon you can convert javascript array to php array via json_decode()

Comment: @Ksyju , i added also the code for javascript array sum , you can check my edited answer

Comment: @canon , yes you are rite mate , by the way i added also code for javascript array sum

Comment: @canon , yes sure